# Deadlock when using two fmt.printlns with a go routine?

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to learn Go and I was experimenting in the playground. I have a very simple go code. I was trying to use Structs and Slices together in a go routine. I am not sure if this will be a thing I will use in production but it seemed a little off, so here:

```
func main() {
    routinemsg := make(chan []Person)
    routinemsg2 := make(chan []Person)

    // create the person records
    p1 := newPerson("john doe", 25)
    p2 := newPerson("dohn joe", 52)
    p3 := newPerson("bohn joo", 30)

    // send a slice of Person to the first routine
    go func() { routinemsg <- []Person{p1, p2} }()

    // retrieve the slice from the first routine[in the append]
    // append p3 to the slice retrieved from the first routine
    // send the new slice to the second routine
    go func() { routinemsg2 <- append(<-routinemsg, p3) }()
    
    // I am able to see the first Println but when I insert the second one I get a deadlock error
    // also, same error if I use one Println with 2 arguments.
    fmt.Println(<-routinemsg)
    fmt.Println(<-routinemsg2)
}
```

I heard about wait groups but dont know them yet! So, be nice to me :D and thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only a single send operation on `routinemsg`, but you have 2 receive operations from it: one in a launched goroutine and another in the `main` goroutine. A sent value can only be received once, by one receiver.

If the launched goroutine receives from `routinemsg` first, then it will be a deadlock: the receive in the `main` will block forever.

If the `main` goroutine would receive first, then the launched goroutine would block forever (trying to receive from it), hence it could never sending anything on `routinemsg2`, hence the receive from `routinemsg2` in `main` would also block forever: deadlock again.

Remove the `fmt.Println(<-routinemsg)` line in `main()`, and then the final receive from `routinemsg2` can (eventually) proceed and will print the slice holding `p1`, `p2` and `p3`:

```
[{john doe 25} {dohn joe 52} {bohn joo 30}]
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/-5D-SmVmFwa).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time! So, instead of receiving the routinemsg2 in 2 different places, I should receive and store it in a variable in one place and use that variable afterwards. Cool! If any, could you share an article or any sort of source about it please?

Comment: The channel does not duplicate data. If you send a value on it, it can be received only once, not multiple times at multiple places. Do note if you store the received value in a variable, accessing the variable from multiple goroutines must be synchronized. You may also choose to send a value twice, or resend once received, but every sent value can only be received once.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplementary to @icza's answer: if you use a *buffered channel* like below,

```
    buffered := make(chan string, 2)
    buffered <- "1"
    buffered <- "2"

    fmt.Println(<-buffered)
    fmt.Println(<-buffered)
```

you can send and receive values more than once from the same channel.

**HOWEVER**, you still limit the times you can send&receive by the argument you pass into **make**! Also, with buffered channels, you will **ALWAYS** receive values in the order they were sent to the channel.

So, second value you receive from the second receiver will always be the second value sent to the channel.